# Three.js - Parse binary STL - RangeError: Out of bounds access

Tags: javascript, laravel, three.js, laravel-8

My goal is to load private stls with [three.js](https://threejs.org/) from my (non-public) Laravel 8 storage folder.

Of course this is not possible with the .load function from the  STLLoader.js like this:

```
const loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x888888, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 2 });

loader.load( '../storage/app/private/file.stl', function ( geometry ) {
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    scene.add( mesh );
});
```

...because the filepath had to point to the private storage outside ob the web-root folder and for that reason it could not work.

My current approach to solve this issue is to make an ajax post request to some STLController where I use the [get method for retrieving file contents from Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#retrieving-files) to get the stl-file contents this way:

```
return Storage::get('private/file.stl');
```

Like this I can now use the response data with the .parse function from the STLLoader.js to use it with three.js.

```
const loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x888888, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 2 });

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: "get_stl_file_contents",
    success: function(data) {

        geometry = loader.parse(data);

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(mesh);
    },
});
```

**This works fine if the STL file is in ascii format, BUT if it is in *binary format* I get the same ERROR message all the time:**

> [ERROR] RangeError: Out of bounds access - (getFloat32)

I either need a way to convert the response data from binari to ascii to use it like I do now OR I would need another way to load/parse an stl for three.js from the raw binary file contents.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How many STL files do you have? Can't you just re-export it into ASCII format using your 3D editor?

Comment: I'm looking at [the latest version of the STLLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js) and it looks like it does support parsing binary formats. Are you using an older version of the Loader? Maybe try updating to the newest version? Alternatively, maybe your binary data is being corrupted somewhere along the way.

Comment: @Marquizzo that's not an option because I constantly get more files through user uploads. Also binary files need way less memory than ascii files.

Comment: I don't exactly know if I'm using the latest version of STLLoader because I installed it as an npm package. How can I check the version of the STLOader? 
The verion of the npm package is: "three": "^0.126.1"
Is it possible that the npm package isn't up to date with the github repo as it is not exactly the same what I've heard?

Comment: How can i check if the file gets corrupted somewhere along the way? It works also just fine when loading it with the .load function and the file path.

Comment: I don’t know Laravel or the method you’re using with `Storage::get()`. But maybe the `data` you’re getting in the AJAX call isn’t the binary you’re expecting. Try to console.log() that data object and see what’s in it.

Comment: @Marquizzo If I console.log() the raw data coming back from the AJAX call it's exactly the same as the actual file content. Also if I paste a simple binary stl file content directly in my js code and try to load it that way, I get the same error both times: **RangeError: Out of bounds access** in the _getFloat32_ function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230434/discussion-between-leonnicklas-and-marquizzo).

Comment: @leonnicklas did you manage to sort it out?

Comment: @ThiagoPetrone yes kind of.... I did it a bit different but maybe it's the right way now. I just posted my answer to my question for you:) Check it out. It's easier than you think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One solution for my problem:**

Just create a specific web route to take control over who may get access to which file and use the three.js STLLoader() as you would  normally. Something like this:

***web.php***

```php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum', 'verified')->group(function () {
    [...]
    Route::get('data/users/{user_id}/{filename}', [FileController::class, 'get_file']);
});
```

***FileController.php***

```php
public function get_file($user_id, $filename): \Illuminate\Http\Response
{
    if (Gate::allows('access-stl') || Auth::id() == $user_id) {
        return $this->return_user_file($user_id, $filename);
    } else {
        abort(403);
    }
}

public function return_user_file($user_id, $filename): \Illuminate\Http\Response
{
    $path = storage_path('app/data/users/'.$user_id.'/'.$filename);

    try {
        $file = File::get($path);
        $type = File::mimeType($path);
        $response = Response::make($file);
        $response->header('Content-Type', $type);

        return $response;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException) {
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

***script.js***

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x888888, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 2 });

loader.load('data/users/1/file.stl', function (geometry) {
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    scene.add(mesh);
});
```